# Replace only whole line containing a string using Sed

Tags: bash, sed

In zabbix-agent.conf I have lines:

```
#   Example: Server=127.0.0.1,192.168.1.0/24,::1,2001:db8::/32,zabbix.example.com
Server=127.0.0.1
```

I want to replace line

```
Server=127.0.0.1
```

with my

```
Server=zabbix.mydomain.com
```

But if I do

```
sed -i -e 's/Server=127.0.0.1/Server=zabbix.mydomain.com/g' /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf
```

it found also line with commented example and replace string in it. I get:

```
#<----->Example: Server=zabbix.mydomain.com,192.168.1.0/24,::1,2001:db8::/32,zabbix.example.com
Server=zabbix.mydomain.com
```

How to replace only one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to

- Match the text at the start of string
- Escape the dots
- Remove `g` flag since the match will only be found at the string start.

Also, you do not need the `-e` option, you can use

```sh
sed -i 's/^Server=127\.0\.0\.1/Server=zabbix.mydomain.com/' /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/IJO14x):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='#   Example: Server=127.0.0.1,192.168.1.0/24,::1,2001:db8::/32,zabbix.example.com
Server=127.0.0.1'
sed 's/^Server=127\.0\.0\.1/Server=zabbix.mydomain.com/g' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
   Example: Server=127.0.0.1,192.168.1.0/24,::1,2001:db8::/32,zabbix.example.com
Server=zabbix.mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '/^Server=127\.0\.0\.1/cServer=zabbix.mydomain.com' file
```

Change line beginning `Server=127.0.0.1` to `Server=zabbix.mydomain.com`.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are almost fine but they would also replace a line like:

```
Server=127.0.0.10
```

A complete solution with any sed could be:

```
sed -i 's/^Server=127\.0\.0\.1$/Server=zabbix.mydomain.com/' /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf
```

`^` and `$` anchor the string to the beginning and end of line, respectively. Dots need backslash escape, else they stand for any character.